# Como delimitar a área de uma div?

Tags: div, css-hover

Estou tentando criar uma div com uma animação :hover.
Coloquei width e height de 100px, porém a animação ocorre passando o mouse em qualquer lugar da tela e não apenas por cima da div. Este é o código que escrevi. Quero que a largura aumente só quando passar o mouse por cima da própria div...

```
.div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    transition: 0.5s;} :hover > .div {width: 400px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Isto aqui

```
:hover > .div {width: 400px;}
```

significa "defina a largura da div filha do elemento sobre o qual está o mouse".

Você quer tratar o mouse sobre a própria div, portanto o correto seria:

```
.div:hover {width: 400px;}
```